# Color.fromArgb dosen't accept integer

Tags: vb.net, colors

In visual basic 2015 the function Color.fromArgb can't accept the integer of the function Color.toArgb
it can accept only the following:

`FromArgb(a As Byte, r As Byte, g As Byte, b As Byte) As Color`

I save an integer from function Color.toArgb from a color dialoge to database. When i try to load and use it by the function Color.fromArgb it doesn't accept the integer as a parameter.

```
ColorDialog1.ShowDialog()
TextBox1.Text = ColorDialog1.Color.ToArgb
TextBox1.ForeColor = ColorDialog1.Color
```

then i recall it

```
TextBox2.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(TextBox1.Text)
```

it gives error.

Is there a simple way to solve this?

Comment: Can you show us some code with actual numbers so that we can try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: There is an overload that does take the argb value: `Function FromArgb(argb As Integer)`

Comment: I get an integer by function Color.toArgb from a color dialoge then save it to database.
When i try to load and use it by the function Color.fromArgb it doesn't accept the integer as a parameter.

Comment: Did any of these solutions help you?

Answer (score 1):

TextBox1.Text is going to return you a string.  First convert it to an integer.  See this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) article for details:

```
Dim number As Integer = Int32.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
```

Then pass the number into FromArgb():

FromArgb() is overloaded.  According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at1k42eh(v=vs.110).aspx), you can pass in integers as well:

```
SolidBrush red = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(120, 255, 0, 0));
```

If you're looking for a simpler option you could do something like:

```
int transparency = 75;
var transparentColor = Color.FromArgb(transparency, Color.Red);
```

Comment: My saved integer is like -16744448 not in 3 numbers.

Comment: The problem seems to be that your passing the wrong type into Color.FromArgb().  Answer updated to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code sample that supports Plutonix's answer

```
Color.FromArgb(CInt(red_txt.Text), CInt(green_txt.Text), CInt(blue_txt.Text))
```

Comment: My saved integer is like -16744448 not in 3 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using a function that converts the integer from Color.FromArgb

```
Function IntegerToColor(ByRef RGB As Int32) As Color
    Dim Bytes As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(RGB)
    Dim Alpha As Byte = Bytes(3)
    Dim Red As Byte = Bytes(2)
    Dim Green As Byte = Bytes(1)
    Dim Blue As Byte = Bytes(0)
    Return Color.FromArgb(Alpha, Red, Green, Blue)
End Function
```

I coped it from another answer and it worked with me

Answer (score 0):

If it does not work remove the alpha parameter

```
Public Shared Function IntegerToColor(ByRef RGB As Int32) As Color
    Dim Bytes As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(RGB)
    'Dim Alpha As Byte = Bytes(3)
    Dim Red As Byte = Bytes(2)
    Dim Green As Byte = Bytes(1)
    Dim Blue As Byte = Bytes(0)
    'Return Color.FromArgb(Alpha, Red, Green, Blue)
    Return Color.FromArgb(Red, Green, Blue)
End Function
```